# Add image to a section in UITableView in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I know how to add an image to a cell in a UITableView, but how can I had an image the same way to the section title ?

Comment: Your title doesn't make it clear that you're asking about the background of the section TITLE rather than the entire section

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same way as you creates and returns cells for tableView's requests you can create and configure view for section header via

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,CGRectGetWidth(tableView.frame), DESIRED_HEADER_HEIGHT)];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithName:@"imageName"]];
    imageView.frame = /*set image where you want*/;
    [headerView addSubview: imageView]
    return headerView;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return DESIRED_HEADER_HEIGHT;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override `UITableViewDelegate` method

`- (UIView*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section`

create an UIImageView with the required image and return it.

```
- (UIView*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img"]];
}
```